# Trying to log in to a website with requests

Tags: python, python-requests

Here is the site: https://nacionalidade.justica.gov.pt/

As you can see there's an input class.
how can I send a request to the site with a paramater that will be sent to the input class?

After I type in my password, the page changes, how can I get the content of the new page?

[image: this is the class I need to send information to]

This is the class I need to send the password to.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

payload = {'password' : 'mypassword... not gonna write it here',
       'ABE4A1723D5F2906F222936AD0E9BE0E' : 
       'ABE4A1723D5F2906F222936AD0E9BE0E'}
url = "https://nacionalidade.justica.gov.pt/"

session_requests = requests.session()
result = session_requests.get(url)

tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='ABE4A1723D5F2906F222936AD0E9BE0E']/@value")))[0]

result = session_requests.post(
    url, 
    data = payload, 
    headers = dict(referer=url)
)

r =requests.get(url,headers= dict(referer = url))
tree = html.fromstring(result.content)
bucket_names = tree.xpath("//div[@class='repo-list--repo']/a/text()")

print(bucket_names)
```

I'm getting an index error and I don't know why

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/?/Desktop/?/?/new.py", line 12, in <module>

authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='ABE4A1723D5F2906F222936AD0E9BE0E']/@value")))[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: @EdekiOkoh added it

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas changed it

Comment: use DevTool in Chrome/Firefox to see request send from browser to server when you login. You will see if it use `POST` and what values it sends. And then you can use `requests.post(..., data=...)` to send it.

Comment: @furas Ok I found the request in the network tab

Comment: For many logins you need to "scrape" the page to extract "nonces" and other fields that can change with every page refresh or login attempt.

Comment: did you check tab `Network` in DevTools - I see POST request with data to url `https://nacionalidade.justica.gov.pt/Home/GetEstadoProcessoAjax`

Comment: BTW: you could save `result.content` in file and open in browser to see what you get from server - maybe there is useful information.

Comment: @furas yeah I found the request, I'm not sure on how to use it. most of the code above is from a tutorial, can you please post an answer on how to use the request.post on the url?

Comment: when you click on request in tab "network" then it should show more information - it shows what parameters it sends. You have to send the same parameters. Test page few times because it may send different values in every requests. And then you have find theses values in HTML and get it. Requests may send data as AJAX/XHR and you may need special header in requests. Sometimes it add also header `User-Agent`. And you can also use `requests.Session()` to get and resend cookies. So problem can be broad and you have to learn more.

Comment: the request has a validation token,password,email,and X-requested-with:something.. basically, how do I build the dictionary to send the data? in what way?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example "How to do it correct way", but without your passwords & etc. So feel free to adopt it for your solution.

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
import requests

session = requests.Session()

html = session.get('https://nacionalidade.justica.gov.pt/').content
form = fromstring(html).xpath('//form')[0]

post = {}
for input in form.inputs:
    if not input.name:
        continue

    post[input.name] = input.value

print('Initial form data')
print(post)

response = session.post('https://nacionalidade.justica.gov.pt/Home/GetEstadoProcessoAjax', data=post)
print(response.text)
```

Outputs

```
Initial form data
{'__RequestVerificationToken': 'p3AmUxqx-6Ipv9EbujoUid5TAKTm76oVmYIaB2UZMv_QzcH7LXaYhGwcQcqXqjWlJjJyvcKgcX48brUkWNvrmz-q3MPlg8mZAm56EGUooYw1', 'SenhaAcesso': '', 'DD94BAEBEF20FBD64FF8CA12170D623D': None, 'Email': None}
<link href="/layout/assets/css/grafico_nacionalidade.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    .titulo {
        color: #3399cc;
    }

    /*Bloco para o estado do processo*/
    #block_container {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    #bloc1
    {
        display:inline;
    }
    #bloc2
    {
        display:inline;
        font-size:1rem;
        font-weight:normal;
    }

    /*-------------------------------------*/

</style>
<div>


        <div id="txtErro" style="background-color:#FBEDED; width:100%; ">
            <div style="padding:35px;">
                A senha <b></b> n&#227;o corresponde a nenhum processo de nacionalidade ativo.
                <p></p>
                <br />
                Verifique que digitou a sua senha corretamente.
                <p></p>
                <br />
                Caso n&#227;o encontre o seu processo dirija-se &#224; <a href="http://www.irn.mj.pt/IRN/sections/irn/contactos">conservat&#243;ria</a> onde entregou o seu pedido.

                Na <a href="http://www.irn.mj.pt/IRN/sections/irn/contactos">Conservatória dos Registos Centrais</a>, em Lisboa, sem marcação prévia é possível obter a sua senha de acesso.
            </div>
        </div>


</div>
<hr />
<p>
    <a href="/Home/PesquisaProcesso">Voltar</a>
</p>
```

> Important:
>
> 1. You have to use one requests session object for all requests because there is cookies session with CSRF token feature activated.
> 2. You have to send all initial form data + your password or security number field
> 3. Maybe you have to send some extra HTTP headers for getting the response since it is an AJAX request (I believe).

Comment: how do i edit the form? meaning, where do i just paste my information to send the correct form? right now some fields are empty

Comment: fill in the empty fields

Comment: form = fromstring(html).xpath('//form')[0] so in what way do I edit the form? I have all the fields just don't know the syntax of writing it. can you add a form with an f string and i'll paste in all the information please?

Comment: You should edit `post` dict object which has the data which will be sent to the server in the final request, not `form` which is an `lxml` element

Comment: so i added my password to the dictionary, and im still getting the same html you're getting

Comment: I added the password to the 'SenhaAcesso' value

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there’s no input with that name. See if you can use a more stable selector.